# Como criar um alert de Confirmação de operação?

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte *Function* que é chamada através de um `OnClick` onde irá excluir o registro seleciona.
Porém por motivos de segurança, gostaria de coloca um controle para continuar com a operação ou não.

Segue código:

```
function DeletarLinha(id) {
            var empresa = null;
            var codigo = null;

            var str = id.replace('d', '');
            if (str.indexOf('_') > 0) {
                var res = str.split("_");
                codigo = (res[0]);
                empresa = (res[1]);

                //Alert de Confirmarção
                //Caso for TRUE
                //Executar essa function ConsultarPedido(codigo, empresa);
                //Caso for Falso
                //Apenas abortar o processo.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var button = $("button")

button.on("click", function(){
  var confirmado = confirm('Deseja deletar?');
  if(confirmado){
   alert('Confirmado!');
  }else{
   alert('Negado!');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Confirmar</button>
```

Utilizando a função 'confirm' você consegue pegar isso do usuário.

Utilizando o seu código:

```
function DeletarLinha(id) {
    var empresa = null;
    var codigo = null;

    var str = id.replace('d', '');
    if (str.indexOf('_') > 0) {
        var res = str.split("_");
        codigo = (res[0]);
        empresa = (res[1]);

        //Alert de Confirmarção
        var confirmado = confirm('Deseja deletar?');
        if(confirmado){
          //Caso for TRUE
          //Executar essa function ConsultarPedido(codigo, empresa);
        }else{
          //Caso for Falso
         //Apenas abortar o processo.
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um `modal` e nesse modal você chamaria a função para fazer a exclusão em si.
Um rascunho rápido, o código abaixo demonstra a ideia de como seria

```js
function exclude(){
 document.getElementById('modal').classList.remove('hidden');
 }

function DeletarLinha(id) {
            var empresa = null;
            var codigo = null;

            var str = id.replace('d', '');
            if (str.indexOf('_') > 0) {
                var res = str.split("_");
                codigo = (res[0]);
                empresa = (res[1]);

                //Alert de Confirmarção
                //Caso for TRUE
                //Executar essa function ConsultarPedido(codigo, empresa);
                //Caso for Falso
                //Apenas abortar o processo.
            }
        }
```

```css
.hidden {
display:none
}
```

```html
<button onClick="exclude()">Excluir</button>

<div id="modal" class="modal hidden">
<p> Você deseja realmente excluir?</p>
<button onClick="closeModal()">Excluir</button>
<button onClick="DeletarLinha(id)">Excluir</button>
</div>
```